# iOS attitude.roll returning random numbers

Tags: ios, cmmotionmanager

I am using Xcode 6.1 and extracting the Pitch and Roll of the phone in the time honoured fashion:

```
valuePitch = degrees(attitude.pitch);
valueRoll = degrees(attitude.roll);
```

with

```
#define degrees(x) (180*x/M_PI)
```

The Pitch returns the correct values. But the Roll, even if the phone is vertical and not moving, will return ranges of numbers like: -168, -114, -131, 167.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it's just fluctuating very rapidly and giving you unexpected results?

Comment: It's updating at around every 0.4s so wouldn't think that's the issue. The confusion is that the Pitch values returned are spot on. Roll jumps all over the place.